# swift syntax, func(var:var:) as a closure?

Tags: swift

I am using firebase authentication and adding a listener for authentication state changes as:

`var handle = auth?.addStateDidChangeListener(self.updateUI(auth:user:))`

while `updateUI` is a function I have created with signature: `(Auth, User?) -> void`

I don't understand the syntax of "(auth:user:)" and was thinking perhaps I need a "," in between auth and user, but that gives me compiler error. I'd appreciate if someone can explain this to me

Comment: What compile error?

Comment: Did my answer answer your question? Do you still have something that you don't understand? If not, please consider accepting my answer.

Answer (score 1):

By writing `updateUI(auth:user:)`, what you are referring to is the method itself, and you are not calling the method immediately. This is an `explicit-member-expression` as the language reference calls it. And the [language reference](https://docs.swift.org/swift-book/ReferenceManual/Expressions.html#grammar_explicit-member-expression) says that one of the forms that an `explicit-member-expression` can take is:

[image]

As you can see from the formal grammar, inside the parentheses, there can be zero or more `argument-name`, and an `argument-name` is an `identifier` followed by the character `:`.

> So why don't you need `,`?

Because the language reference says so. :)

If you think about it, the `:` is already delimiting the different parameter labels, so you don't need an extra delimiter.

> Why write out the parameter labels in the first place?

It is likely to avoid ambiguity. There's probably another overload of `updateUI` with different parameter labels, so just saying `updateUI` could be ambiguous. If there is only one `updateUI`, then you can just say `updateUI`.